# Why does ATMs have a green plastic thing in front of card reader?

Tags: atm

[image]

To me this looks suspicious, it looks easy to hide a skimming device here.

A slot flush to the front would be safer, in my opinion.

Comment: A slot flush to the front would be utterly trivial to mount a flat skimmer over.

Comment: Not if you knew nothing is supposed to be in front of the slot, that the entire surface should be flat.

Comment: The question really is: why do ATM swallow?

Comment: If they swallow your card, you must have been doing something wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily. Legitimate reasons where the user does nothing illegal include: Lebanese Loop, EMV chip damage and the ATM has an error. But fraud is often the reason: https://www.lovemoney.com/news/73170/atm-swallowed-card-cash-machine-problem-help-bank

Answer (score 2):

> There has been a constant rise in ATM frauds and scams most specifically ATM skimming effecting consumers secured transactions. In order to combat ATM skimming ATM machine manufacturers are manufacturing ATM with anti skimming technologies which appear as a green casing that protrudes from the card insertion slot. Many a times there are chances that ATM thefts might occur by simply mirroring these anti skimming parts, for which one should always remain careful. - [What is the green thing on the card reader at ATMs?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-green-thing-on-the-card-reader-at-ATMs)

But ATM MagStripe skimmers still exist! [image]

*[Green Skimmers Skimming Green](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2011/03/green-skimmers-skimming-green/)*

Despite the flawed anti-skimming system, it's worth realising that the credit/debit card's magnetic stripe is inserted perpendicular (longways) allows for easy skimming.

Being flush would also allow for skimming devices to be connected, only much easier.

> ATM manufacturer Diebold claims to have found the answer to skimming fraud with a new reader that requires users to insert their card sideways on to prevent the copying of data stored on the magnetic stripe. - [Diebold takes 90-degree shift to counter ATM skimming](https://www.finextra.com/news/fullstory.aspx?newsitemid=27032)

With all this knowledge, why not discontinue magnetic stripe and end the raising fraud pandemic?

> Replacing the 15 million payment terminals in the United States would cost roughly $6.75 billion, according to Javelin’s estimates. - [Why Is the U.S. Determined to Have the Least-Secure Credit Cards in the World?](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2016/03/us-determined-to-have-the-least-secure-credit-cards-in-the-world/473199/)

Alright, so it's actually more economical for banks to have an annual reserve to pay fraud costs than overhauling the current infrastructure.

> Even if the US merchants had surpassed the 75% adoption stage, however, it would still be prudent to include a magnetic stripe on the back of chip cards to ensure that no payment transaction will be lost, within or outside of the country, as a result of the lack of an updated merchant payment system. [Why do credit cards with a smart chip still have a magnetic strip on the back of them?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-credit-cards-with-a-smart-chip-still-have-a-magnetic-strip-on-the-back-of-them)